# lost connection to mysql server during query - c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I read most of similar posts and I didn't get answers. I'm using cppconn library and everything is on the same server (not remote) and db is too small. what is the possible solutions? 
this section is the only try catch part and runs for one time and the other parts is not inside try catch. so I think the error raises from this part.

```
try{
    db_driver = get_driver_instance();
    db_conn = db_driver->connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    db_conn->setSchema(DB_NAME);
    db_prepstmt2 = db_conn->prepareStatement("DELETE FROM cs");
    db_prepstmt2->executeQuery();
    db_prepstmt2 = db_conn->prepareStatement("ALTER TABLE cs AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
    db_prepstmt2->executeQuery();
    db_prepstmt2 = db_conn->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cs VALUES(default, ?, ?)");
    db_prepstmt2->setInt(2, 1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
    {
        db_prepstmt2->setInt(1, i);
        db_prepstmt2->executeQuery();
    }
} 
catch (sql::SQLException &e) 
{
    cout << "#ERR: " << e.what() << " MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode() << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the error code, error message and SQL state? Have you traced how far the code goes? Which is the statement triggering the exception?

Comment: Output: Terminate called after throwing an instance of sql::SQLException
what(): lost connection to mysql server during query

Comment: I don't see #ERR: in output

Comment: Then the exception is thrown somewhere else.

Comment: this is the only try catch in my code

Comment: The output is not from any catch statement, but from runtime. When an exception isn't caught, it unwinds the stack and calls [`terminate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) eventually.